# Sanic OpenAPI Swagger docs generation throws attribute paths operationId is repeated

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, sanic

I am using sanic to build a simple API. I have two end points defined:

```
from sanic import Blueprint, response
from sanic_openapi import doc

bp = Blueprint('default', url_prefix="", version=2, strict_slashes=True)


@bp.get("")
@doc.summary('Default GET endpoint for API v2')
async def route_get(request):
    resp = {"message": "New API - GET", "version": 2.0}
    return response.json(resp)


@bp.post("")
@doc.summary('Default POST endpoint for API v2')
async def route_post(request):
    resp = {"message": "New API - POST", "version": 2.0}
    return response.json(resp)
```

The generated swagger documents fails validation, with the following message

Error:

```
"attribute paths.'/v2/'(post).operationId is repeated",
```

I am expecting to have several routes that have multiple HTTP verbs going to the same path:

```
GET /v2/product
POST /v2/product 

DELETE /v2/product/{id}
PUT /v2/product/{id}
```

I've tested with these endpoints too, and I get two errors about operationId being repeated. One is for the `/v2/product` path and one is for `/v2/product/{id}`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You have to specify the `operationId`:  
 [https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/)  

=> `@doc.operationId('getProducts')`  


=> `@doc.operationId('postProduct')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below code can help , So that you can use the same path for POST,GET,PUT,DELETE Separately and write your own logic.

I have Modified your Code a Little Bit , Here below is the code :

```
from sanic import Blueprint, response
from sanic_openapi import doc

bp = Blueprint('default', url_prefix="", version=2, strict_slashes=True)

@bp.get("/<product_id:int>", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary('Default GET endpoint for API v2')
async def route_get(request):
    resp = {"message": "New API - GET", "version": 2.0}
    return response.json(resp)


@bp.put("/<product_id:int>", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary('Default POST endpoint for API v2')
async def route_post(request):
    resp = {"message": "New API - POST", "version": 2.0}
    return response.json(resp)
```

If you have to use the Model Object with product , You can use something like the below, I have Created a full fledged example for your reference.

Folder Structure :

```
 Project
    blueprints
        product.py
    data.py
    main.py
    models.py
```

product.py

```
from sanic.blueprints import Blueprint
from sanic.response import json
from sanic_openapi import doc

from models import Product
from data import test_product


blueprint = Blueprint('Products', '/products')

@blueprint.get("/<product_id:int>", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary("Fetches a product with product Id")
def route_get(request, product_id):
    resp = {"message": "New API - GET", "version": 2.0}
    return json(resp)


@blueprint.put("/<product_id:int>", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary("Updates a Product with the Updated product Details from the contends from Body")
@doc.consumes(Product, location='body')
def route_post(request, product_id):
    resp = {"message": "New API - POST", "version": 2.0}
    return json(resp)
```

data.py

```
from models import Product
import datetime

test_product = Product()

test_product = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Gross'
}
```

main.py

```
from sanic import Sanic

from sanic_openapi import swagger_blueprint
from blueprints.product import blueprint as product_blueprint

app = Sanic()

app.blueprint(product_blueprint)

app.config.API_VERSION = '1.0.0'
app.config.API_TITLE = 'Product API'

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

models.py

```
from sanic_openapi import doc

class Product:
    id = int
    name = str
```

Now running `python main.py`

Console Output :

```
[2019-11-22 16:20:53 +0530] [15744] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2019-11-22 16:20:53 +0530] [15744] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-11-22 16:20:53 +0530] [15744] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-11-22 16:20:53 +0530] [15744] [INFO] Starting worker [15744]
```

**Accessing Swagger UI with API :**

If You have to use a Class based view Demonstration , Here below are the two files which can help.

```
Project Structure
 Project
     main.py
     blueprint.py
```

main.py

```
from sanic_openapi import doc
from sanic_openapi import swagger_blueprint
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

from blueprint import blueprint

app = Sanic()

app.blueprint(swagger_blueprint)
app.blueprint(blueprint)


@app.get("/product", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary("Displays the Product Details ")
async def get_product(request):
    return json({})

@app.post("/product", strict_slashes=True)
@doc.summary("Creates a product in Repositary")
@doc.consumes({"product": {"name": str}}, location="body")
async def create_product(request):
    return json({})


app.config.API_VERSION = 'pre-alpha'
app.config.API_TITLE = 'Display Products Demonstration API'

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

blueprint.py

```
from sanic.blueprints import Blueprint
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView
from sanic_openapi import doc
from sanic.response import json

blueprint = Blueprint('Class-based View', url_prefix='/class-based-view')
class MyView(HTTPMethodView):
    @doc.summary("Get my view")
    def get(self, request):
        return json({"method": "GET"})

    @doc.summary("Post my view")
    @doc.consumes({"view": {"name": str}}, location="body")
    def post(self, request):
        return json({"method": "POST"})


blueprint.add_route(MyView.as_view(), '/view', strict_slashes=True)
```

Now run `python main.py`

```
[2019-11-22 16:50:41 +0530] [12212] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2019-11-22 16:50:41 +0530] [12212] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-11-22 16:50:41 +0530] [12212] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-11-22 16:50:41 +0530] [12212] [INFO] Starting worker [12212]
```

You can now see the SWAGGER UI at http://localhost:8000/swagger/